# Is it common that hostels charge more for woman only dorm rooms?

Tags: hostels, female-travellers, discrimination, price

When I was in Tbilisi (Georgia), during my one week trip, 3 months ago, I found out in **some** hostels the women only dorm rooms have higher prices than mixed dorm rooms with equal numbers of bed or room size, while there was no men only room!

Is it common in the other countries too to find women only dorm rooms with higher prices than mixed dorm rooms(I do not mean Muslim countries)?

P.S: I didn't write **all** because I was not able to search for all hostels in a country or a big city rationally! In this situation, common easily means finding such samples in the other countries more than rarely and as an accepted readable or unreadable rule. There were some women only dorm rooms which were smaller with less beds than mixed dorm rooms but there is no reason to give the smaller one to women to get higher charges.

Comment: If you already say that there were only "some" hostels doing that, is that really "common"?

Comment: I can't say all because I am not able to search for all hostels in a country or big city rationally and it doesn't need any extra explanation as it is obvious! In this situation, common easily means finding such samples in the other country more than rarely.

Comment: "common"? What's common? 5? 50? Or do you just mean do they exist elsewhere.  I'd rephrase to be more clear - as 'what is common' can be subjective, and might be the reason you've got a close vote already :/

Comment: I've never come across this before and I've stayed and worked in lots of hostels, including in Tbilisi. What you do see however is higher prices for smaller dorms and lower prices for larger dorms. If the women-only dorm had fewer beds in it then that would naturally lead to a higher price. Room sizes are dictated by the building you have and it's far more common for women to want to avoid mixed dorms than it is for men though I have had a couple of men specify they only want a single-sex dorm.

Comment: Some capsule hotels in Japan don't accept women. I think their rationale is that they don't want the area to be mixed-gender, and they don't think there's enough women to make a woman-only floor of a hotel economically viable. My suspicion is that in Georgia, there aren't many females using hostels, so women-only rooms would have fewer users than mixed-gender, so they charge a premium. I don't think that's fair or rational, but that'd be my guess.

Comment: My experience is proving something else. There were equal alone female travelers to male alone travelers at least in the hostels that I found. I agree about not being rational or fair with you.

Comment: I can imagine there were significantly more mixed dorm rooms than women-only dorm rooms. If the women-only dorm rooms are always fully booked, while the mixed ones are not, I can imagine this choice.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: There's plenty of females using hostels in Georgia. I'd say close to 50% actually.

Comment: This is at least unheard of in Western countries, as that would probably qualify as sex-based discrimination. And while I do travel quite often and outside Western paths, that's the first time I hear of such a thing!

Comment: @tricasse It was interesting for me as it was my first time trying hostels!!

Comment: From financial point of view it's logical that they'd charge more for dorms rooms where they discriminate against big part of potential clients, be it "women-only", "whites-only", "muslim-only" or whatever. OTOH, for example in Europe "women-only" rooms would be either illegal or in the grey zone. You cannot discriminate based on sex.

Comment: @Vertec No at all! It is not a sex discrimination if you have women-only dorm rooms in a world which there are more female victims by rape than male victims by rape but it is a kind of sex discrimination if you charge more to protect women from rape and an unsafe environment because of men! It is not comparable with race discrimination or color discrimination or religion discrimination. Women travelers want a safe environment and when you have many reports of rape and women trafficking during staying in an unsafe environment it would be a sex discrimination to charge more to provide safety.

Comment: About being illegal please show your evidences that proves women-only dorm rooms in hostels is illegal in the Europe. I think you have misunderstood it with forcing women to choose women-only dorm rooms!In my travels I found many European,American and Asian women who wanted women only dorm rooms because they didn't feel safe in mixed sex dorm rooms.If your statements are true about Europe it can be a dangerous case which falls in danger women safety and individual choices of people. No one can force women to experience an unsafe environment against their own will.

Comment: And an evidence that your claim is not true about Europe: http://www.hostelbookers.com/article/travel-for-women/female-friendly-hostels-europe/

Comment: @vartec you couldn't be more wrong. 'women-only' facilities are very common in Europe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well...this is difficult to answer, because how many is 'common'? However, I've stayed in hostels in Australia, New Zealand, all over Europe, Central and northern Asia, USA/Canada and South America, and I can't recall a time that I've seen them charge EXTRA for female dorms - EXCEPT when there were fewer beds.

Now, it's fairly common to charge more for smaller dorms - fewer snorers, people to steal your stuff or whatever.  It's more common to sometimes put an excess on some rooms to make them 'special' and include breakfast with just those rooms.

I've also seen it where single guys weren't allowed to stay in the mixed dorm room - only couples, which I'd say was bordering on discrimination. This was in Philadelphia, US.  But it was the same price as the all-male dorm room.

I think, as @hippietrail commented, in most western countries this practise would be considered gender discrimination - charging people extra based on their gender, although I think a good lawyer could argue it's charging for security.  However, for whatever the reason, I can confirm that no, it's not common at all, and if I saw a woman being charged extra for this, I'd certainly be arguing discrimination.

However, I've not stayed in many hostels in SE Asia, Africa or the Middle East (although I've been to a few countries in these areas, for whatever reason I stayed in guesthouses or hotels), and perhaps in those cultures it may be different.

Comment: How is it discrimination? The woman is perfectly entitled to stay in the mixed dorm if she wants. She's not being forced to be charged extra, she just has an option to pay extra if she so desires.

Comment: Sure, if it's available. But say only mens and female dorms are left, and the female ones cost more, then she is being charged more than a guy would staying at the same place.

Comment: Ah I didn't consider you were comparing to male-only dorms. From my experience they are a lot less common than mixed or female. If it *was* the case that the female dorm was more expensive then the male *equivalent* then we are of course talking about discrimination. The OP however was only comparing prices between female and mixed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. It's obviously natural and logic way to do.

If you have women-only dorms, you risk being not able to take extra backpacker even when you technically have free places (if they happen to be in female dorm and the backpacker is male) so they actually costs you more. You don't want to have a lot of female-only dorms so you want to discourage girls from using them and encourage them to choose mixed dorm instead (because it's cheaper).

Many women don't want to sleep in the same room with the unfamiliar men (for any reason), and it's why the hostels have the female-only dorms anyway.

It's not a discrimination that single-sex rooms are more expensive, because women are allowed to choose mix room if they want. Only because some of them don't want, hostels provide single-sex rooms as the extra service. I haven't ever seen a male-only dorm in a hostel, but it's simply because (generally speaking, in european culture) men wouldn't be interested in paying more only to have the guarantee to have guys only in the room (and probably more mess and more snoring).

Please note that my remark is for, generally speaking, 'Western-culture' countries. There are some countries which object unfamiliar men and women in the same dorm for religious grounds.

Comment: The financial aspect you mention might make sense. However I believe no hostel would risk being accused of gender discrimination just to make a few extra bucks.

Comment: @JoErNanO but there's no discrimination. Women pay exactly the same - when they choose the mixed room. And single sex rooms are more expensive because they are more problematic to utilize.

Comment: The question is about women paying more to use female-only dorms. This could be interpreted as gender discrimination, as pointed out in the other answers and comments.

Comment: @JoErNanO women are not paying more to use female-only dorms is not discrimination because men can't use it. Lack of men-only dorms *could* be perceived as discrimination, however it's very unlikely, because people wanting to sleep only in one-sex rooms tend to be only women.